# Fastest way to append two or more Text files together (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, winapi

**What is the fastest way to append two or more Text files together (Windows 7)?**

I am currently using using the TYPE command in a Command Prompt but I would have to think there is some sort of Windows API that could be faster than the TYPE command. I would like a solution that will allow the file to still be opened in SHARE mode by other users.

**Also is there a way to have the process run on the server?**

In the example below, F: and T: are on different servers. I would think if I was to RDPed into one of the two servers it should run faster.

**Here is what I am doing currently**
These commands are in a Batch File

```
TYPE F:\1112\ELEIMR11.TXT >  T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\1112\ELEIMR12.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\1301\ELEIMR13.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\1400\ELEIMR14.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\1400\ELEIMR17.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\1600\ELEIMR16.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\2200\ELEIMR22.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\2400\ELEIMR24.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\2500\ELEIMR25.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\2800\ELEIMR28.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\5000\ELEIMR50.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\5100\ELEIMR51.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\5500\ELEIMR55.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\5700\ELEIMR57.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\6000\ELEIMR60.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\7600\ELEIMR76.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\7800\ELEIMR78.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\8300\ELEIMR83.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\8700\ELEIMR87.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\8800\ELEIMR88.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\9100\ELEIMR91.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\J200\ELEIMRJ2.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\J400\ELEIMRJ4.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\J600\ELEIMRJ6.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\J700\ELEIMRJ7.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\K100\ELEIMRK1.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\K200\ELEIMRK2.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
TYPE F:\K400\ELEIMRK4.TXT >> T:\0000\ELEIMR00.TXT
```

Comment: superuser.com is a better place for such question.  you can use copy file1 + file2 to concatenate files.  This will also be faster than using type.

Comment: The command doesn't matter.  This only goes as fast as it can be read off the disk.  To speed it up you need a faster disk.

Comment: @hans-passant The command does matter.  output redirection results in small writes, copy is more optimized and uses larger I/O size.  It can also use IOCTL_COPYCHUNK (although it seems to use it only with single file copy not for append)

Comment: *but I would have to think there is some sort of Windows API that could be faster than the TYPE command* I think you want `BOOL SHConcatonateTwoTextFilesTogetherFast(SHITEMID *pSource, SHITEMID *pDestination)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they're on different servers, I'm guessing that this operation is going to be IO bound.  Try concatenating all the files to a local file first, (preferably on a different local disk), zipping the file, copying it to the other box and unzipping it there.  If they're both Windows boxes, you coulc concat them all into a local compressed folder and copy that over.